# init a NSWindow in monomac

Tags: nswindow, monomac

This is driving me nuts, I've tried everything for about a week. Hope some kind sole can help. I'm trying to create a new modal popup color picker. However, `StopModal()` keeps creating a new window.

I created a new `NSWindow` programatically a little like this:

```
class ColorPicker:NSWindow{

    void ColorPicker(IntPtr Value):base(Value){
    }

    void ColorPicker(Color StartColor){
      //Set up window here.
    }

    public void ShowModal(NSWindow NewParent){
        this.ParentWindow = NewParent;
        NSApplication.SharedApplication.RunModalForWindow(this);    
        return DialogResult;
    }
}
```

I create like this:

```
ColorPicker CP=new ColorPicker(Color.Red);
```

Then show it

```
CP.ShowDialog(MyMainWindow);
```

I have a button on the form that closes it and calls

```
NSApplication.SharedApplication.StopModal();
```

But for some reason this creates a second window by calling:

```
void ColorPicker(IntPtr Value):base(Value){
}
```

Then I get leak errors and soon it crashes:

```
NativeRelease ERROR]: type: ColorPicker handle: 137041376 count: 2 gchandle: 0

objc[350]: Object 0x103070 of class NSConcreteMapTable autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be happening if you are not retaining a reference to the ColorPicker object in .NET.  It will be garbage collected, then re-created when the Cocoa/objective-c system tries to send it a message.

Happens to me when I Dispose of the object after it closes.

Comment: Sound plausible. I am disposing the window after it closes and I have seen a couple of times messages going through sendevents to the window afterwards and screwing things up.How would I resolve this?

Comment: Only way I found is to not dispose of the window.  I haven't found any way to do it otherwise without errors..

Comment: That's what I've decided to do. Just store and keep reusing the same windows. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just don't call .Dispose().  It will be garbage collected after the objective-c releases it completely..